# Group by and then filter

Tags: javascript, json, filter, underscore.js

I have below Object with me.

```
car = [{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: true,
    Name: "Park Street",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 2",
    Date: "2018/03/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 3",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 4",
    Date: "2018/05/01"
}];
```

I have to get only one element from each group of  "Acc". One element for each of Acc:"X1" and Acc:"X2". Logic to find that should be if primary: true, then select that element from the group else pick the one having latest Date: value.

I do understand this requirement can be achievable using underscore js but I am new in this and can't figure out the relevant way.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Thanks! Updated my question. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, is first group by `Acc`, and then within the group sort by `primary` & `Date` descending, and then just pick the first of each group.

eg.

```js
const car = [{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: true,
    Name: "Park Street",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 2",
    Date: "2018/03/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 3",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 4",
    Date: "2018/05/01"
}];


//lets group
const grouped = car.reduce((a, v) => {
  if (!a[v.Acc]) a[v.Acc] = [];
  a[v.Acc].push(v);
  return a;
}, {});

//now for each group sort by primary, and then Date
const result = Object.values(grouped).map((g) => {
  g.sort((a, b) => b.primary - a.primary || b.Date.localeCompare(a.Date));
  return g[0]; //now sorted, pick first.
});

console.log(result);
```

Another more efficient way, might be just to keep track of the best inside an object literal..

eg..

```js
const car = [{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: true,
    Name: "Park Street",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 2",
    Date: "2018/03/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 3",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 4",
    Date: "2018/05/01"
}];

const best = {};

car.forEach((c) => {
  const b = best[c.Acc] = best[c.Acc] || c;
  if (b.primary) return;
  if (c.Date.localeCompare(best.Date) < 0) best[c.Acc] = c;
});

console.log(Object.values(best));
```

Comment: Hi Keith! Thanks a lot. But is this in Javascript or other scriptings?

Comment: @SaikatNeogy  It's Javascript, if it wasn't clicking the "Run code snippet" above would not work..

Comment: Hi Keith! I am getting syntax error on the line with arrow when I try to use this as javascript.

Comment: Are you using the worst browser on the planet, aka IE11 by any chance?

Comment: I am using it in an Offline version of Veeva.

Comment: Never heard of Veeva,.  But if it doesn't support arrow functions, then maybe there are worse browsers than IE... :)   But if the arrow functions is something it does not like, you can change to regular one.. eg.. `(c) => {`  make  `function (c) {`   If your into Javascript programmer for the long run, I would also advice looking into transpiling Javascript, nothing worse than having to work with old ES5 Javascript.. :(

Comment: Hi Keith Can you please add the change in your answer for the first approach only. Please? I am new to work with javascript.

Comment: Personally I'd rather not change the code in the answer, as I personally think it's better as is.  But what I can do is show you a nice website that will do this for you -> http://babeljs.io/repl  If you copy paste the above code into the left & make sure the ES2015 preset is selected, you will see the transformed code on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned Underscore, I understand you can use external libraries. This is the same approach as [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith) did, but using [Lodash](https://lodash.com) instead.

Also, this should work with all browsers.

```js
var car = [{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: true,
    Name: "Park Street",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X1",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 2",
    Date: "2018/03/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 3",
    Date: "2018/01/01"
},{
    Acc: "X2",
    primary: false,
    Name: "Park Street 4",
    Date: "2018/05/01"
}];

var sorted = _.orderBy(car, ['primary', 'Date'], ['desc', 'desc']);
var groupedSorted = _.groupBy(sorted, 'Acc');
var result = _.flatMap(groupedSorted, function(o) { return o[0]; });
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if primary: true, then select that element from the group else pick the one having latest Date: value

As per the above statement there is only one `primary:true` in each group (`X1` or `X2`). If my understanding is correct you can try below code **:**

```js
// Input object
var car = [{
 Acc: "X1",
 primary: true,
 Name: "Park Street",
 Date: "2018/01/01"
}, {
 Acc: "X1",
 primary: false,
 Name: "Park Street 2",
 Date: "2018/03/01"
}, {
 Acc: "X2",
 primary: false,
 Name: "Park Street 3",
 Date: "2018/01/01"
}, {
 Acc: "X2",
 primary: false,
 Name: "Park Street 4",
 Date: "2018/05/01"
}];

// fetch the primary:true objects from the Input array.
var primaryTrueArray = car.filter(obj => {
  if (obj.primary === true) {
    return obj;
  }
});

// filtered out the primary:true objects from the Input array based on the primaryTrueArray.Hence, we will get all primary:false.
var filteredOutPrimaryTrue = car.filter(obj => primaryTrueArray.filter(item => item.Acc != obj.Acc));

// Fetch the latest date from the group who has primary:false from the filteredOutPrimaryTrue.
var latestDateFromGroup = filteredOutPrimaryTrue.sort(function(a,b){
                                   if (a.Date < b.Date)
                                      return 1;
                                   else if (a.Date == b.Date)
                                      return 0;
                                   else
                                      return -1;
                               });
                               
// Concatenate both the arrays "primaryTrueArray & latestDateFromGroup" into single one.                           
var finalResult = primaryTrueArray.concat([latestDateFromGroup[0]]); 

// Desired output.
console.log(finalResult);
```